# Validating a username with preg_match according to various criteria

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

So im continuing on my php journey. Now creating registration form and validating usernames requested by the user. This is what i have so far:

```
if (preg_match("([a-z 0-9](?=.{3})(?!.{10}))", $user_Name))
```

I used "RegExr" to create this match however it just doesn't seem to be working. Added a capital letter and it still said it was valid

Was going for:

- Numbers from 0 - 9
- No capital letters
- no special symbols at all
- min of 6 characters
- max of 10 characters

Comment: Forcing user to have username length between 6 and 10 characters is awful. Is there any real reason for such length limitation?

Comment: I chose to use the 10 length maximum as i wanted to create cleaner more professional usernames... Do you suggest i change this?

Comment: Lots of users use their first+last name as username (like I do) and for people like me it is awfull. What is 'professional' about limiting username to 10 symbols?

Comment: okay ill switch this up then thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 9):

According to your rules this should work:

```
if (preg_match('/^[a-z0-9]{6,10}$/', $user_name))
```

Answer (score -1):

After about 3 hours researching and troubleshooting I found the correct solution. Turns out that the order is very important:

(?=.{5}) <=== string must be 5 or more

(?!.{11}) <=== string must be no more than 10 characters

^[a-z 0 -9]+$ <=== matches any string with only common letters and numbers from 0 -9

```
if (!preg_match('/(?=.{5})(?!.{11})^[a-z 0 -9]+$/', $user_Name)) {
            echo 'username is not valid</br>';
            echo $user_Name;
        }
        else {
            echo 'username is valid</br>';
            echo $user_Name;
        }
```

Comment: I already answered your question. What you are doing now is just plain wrong. `(?=.{5})`means that you can have 5 of any characters before, thus ##### is a valid username. And `[a-z 0 -9]` should be `[a-z0-9]` otherwise spaces is allowed. I even think that would mean a-z, spaces, hyphens and 9.

Comment: @NicholasRuunu is right, use his pattern. Your pattern is not correct, if you test it pr openly you will find this out.

Comment: Im testing it now and for some odd reason it works :/... Sigh im so confused